# Finite State Machine without recursion

Tags: finite-automata, terminology

I have found utility in state machines that do not have the complexity of recursion: no self or ancestral transitions.

Is there a name for this sub-category of FSMs? Are they commonly used or considered broadly useful?

Comment: Consider tagging [tag:terminology].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decision trees [1] are a class of hierarchical control structures that might be what you are looking for.

[1] Decision tree in Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree